# AmCharts XY Chart - How to get modal popup on click in Angular?

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

We need to show a modal window show when users click on a data point.

The code we have is:

```
  constructor(public dataservice: DataserviceService, private modalService: NgbModal, private router: Router) { }
  ...
  ...
  bullet.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
    console.log(ev.target._dataItem.dataContext);
    this.modalService.open(this.dialog);
  });
}

public showDialog() {
  this.modalService.open(this.dialog);
}
```

[image]
We are able to see the log data in console.. but not the modal. How can we solve this?

Comment: can you post the import part of NgbModal and what is dialog

Comment: Can you make sure that you're using the same context `this` in your handler?  I mean replace `function (ev) {` with `(ev) =>`

Comment: does showDialog works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine, however as @yurzui mentioned, the problem lies here

```
bullet.events.on("hit", function (ev) {}
```

since the it will be called from another context the modalService is not available there. Try using a arrow-function so the this context is preserved.To fix this,

```
bullet.events.on("hit", (ev) => {
    console.log(ev.target._dataItem.dataContext);
    this.modalService.open(this.dialog);
 });
```